# How can I speed up the graphic display on an HP Mini 110 series?

Tags: graphics, performance

I have an HP Mini 110 series, and I see that anything that involves grahics or window management is getting very slow. I have the usual 1GB of RAM and the Atom N450 processor.

Is there any special driver I should find for the graphics processor?

Thanks :-)

JF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar device and I do the following:

- Disable Session Applications:

  - GUI: System Menu -> Preferences -> Session Applications
  - CLI: `gnome-session-properties`

    - Disable things that you dont use or like, such as Visual Assistance, Remote Desktop, Verify New Drivers and so on.
- Disable Session Graphics (like chris said)

  - GUI: System menu -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Visual Effects -> Select 'None'
  - CLI: `gnome-appearance-properties` -> Visual Effects -> Select 'None'
- Disable unused daemons (install application rcconf).

  - CLI: `sudo apt-get instal rcconf`

    - Run it: `sudo rcconf` and disable daemons by pressing "Space".
    - Some daemons to disable are: brltty, bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable compositing. This used for graphic effects but is not really required for most applications.

> System menu> Preferences> Appearance--> Visual Effects--> Select 'None'